# How to check if an ordered non-consecutive subsequence is in array? Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, search, subsequence

I'd be surprised if this hasn't been asked yet.

Let's say I have an array `[5,6,7,29,34]` and I want to check if the sequence `5,6,7` appears in it (which it does). Order does matter.

How would I do this?

Comment: Like substring or like subsequence?

Comment: I assume order matters? eg. `[1, 2]` matches `[1, 2, 3, 4]` but not `[3, 2, 1, 4]`.

Comment: @ChristianDean yes, order matters.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Subsequence? Though I'm not entirely sure what the difference is.

Comment: Do you consider `[5,7,29]` a "subarray" of `[5,6,7,29,34]`? It **is** a subsequence.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Right, that makes more sense

Comment: Ok but then you shouldn't call pythad's solution "perfect", since that only detects substring-like subarrays.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger **You** don't know the difference between substring and subsequence? I'm surprised.

Comment: @StefanPochmann That "duplicate" question relates no answer to this question. Order and consecutive elements matters in this one, while the other does not.

Comment: @Graviton Sounds like you're confused. The answers there do work for your question. Why are you saying now that "consecutive elements matters"? Earlier you clearly confirmed that it doesn't.

Comment: @StefanPochmann My bad, must have misread the question.

Comment: @Graviton I see you actually changed the question now. Or rather attempted to. Because right now it contradicts itself, as `[5,6,7]` **is** a subsequence of `[5,6,4,7]`, so the answer should be `True`. Anyway, questions shouldn't be changed like that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I thought so, what terminology would fix that?

Comment: Read my very first comment again and have a guess. But again, questions shouldn't be changed like that. You made it absolutely clear that you're talking about subsequences (since I gave you an example with a non-continuous subsequence and you acknowledged it and then you renamed your question to say subsequence). Changing it away from subsequence would invalidate a correct answer. That's not cool.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here is a quick (very quick) and dirty (very dirty) solution (that is somewhat flawed, so don't really use this):

```
>>> str([5,6,7]).strip('[]') in str([5,6,7,29,34])
True
```

The RightWay™ is likely to use [*list.index()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) to find candidate matches for the first element and then verify the full match with slicing and list equality:

```
>>> def issubsequence(sub, seq):
        i = -1
        while True:
            try:
                i = seq.index(sub[0], i+1)  # locate first character
            except ValueError:
                return False
            if seq[i : i+len(sub)] == sub:  # verify full match
                return True         

>>> issubsequence([5, 6, 7], [5,6,7,29,34])
True
>>> issubsequence([5, 20, 7], [5,6,7,29,34])
False
```

Edit: The OP clarified in a comment that the subsequence must be in order but need not be in consecutive positions.  That has a different and much more complicated solution which was already answered here:  [How do you check if one array is a subsequence of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174985/how-do-you-check-if-one-array-is-a-subsequence-of-another)

Comment: Meh, that also says `True` for `str([5,6,7]).strip('[]') in str([55,6,7,29,34])`.

Comment: And your added solution fails `issubsequence([1, 3], [1, 2, 3])`. It says `False` instead of the correct `True`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann No it doesn't. I'm getting `False` as the output.

Comment: @StefanPochmann The OP wants to match only subsequences that appear in the same order as the sublist. Right? That is what he told me: _"@ChristianDean yes, order matters."_.

Comment: @ChristianDean Huh? It **is** the same order. Pretty sure you don't know the difference between substring and subsequence. The original question version wasn't clear about what they wanted, but since Raymond explicitly called it subsequence, it's wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't call a simple two-liner *"much more complicated"* :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ah, I see what you mean. Normally when I hear someone refer to subsequence, they mean that a match must be in _consectuitve_ order. But I see now that is not the [formally definition of a subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence). You're right, I didn't fully understand the difference. Thanks for helping me learn that!

Comment: @ChristianDean Yeah, apparently so many people don't know the definitions that Wikipedia's articles for substring and subsequence each right away reference the other and warn that one shouldn't confuse them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution:

```
def is_sublist(a, b):
    if not a: return True
    if not b: return False
    return b[:len(a)] == a or is_sublist(a, b[1:])
```

As mentioned by Stefan Pochmann this can be rewritten as:

```
def is_sublist(a, b):
    return b[:len(a)] == a or bool(b) and is_sublist(a, b[1:])
```

Comment: "Beautiful" solution... you're so sure of yourself :) ... More seriously, you could even do `if not a: return True; if not b: return False`...

Comment: Perfect, you could probably lambda-ify that if one wanted to as well.

Comment: If you're going to use this, just keep in mind that it hits the recursion limit fairly quickly. A 1000 element list is a no-go.

Comment: Could just do `return b[:len(a)] == a or bool(b) and is_sublist(a, b[1:])`. Your two ifs don't really help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works (efficiently!) on any pair of iterable objects:

```
import collections
import itertools

def consume(iterator, n=None):
    """Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."""
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)

def is_slice(seq, subseq):
    """Returns whether subseq is a contiguous subsequence of seq."""
    subseq = tuple(subseq)  # len(subseq) is needed so we make it a tuple.
    seq_window = itertools.tee(seq, n=len(subseq))
    for steps, it in enumerate(seq_window):
        # advance each iterator to point to subsequent values in seq.
        consume(it, n=steps)
    return any(subseq == seq_slice for seq_slice in izip(*seq_window))
```

`consume` comes from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).