# How to find if one array is a subset of another array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, collections

Preferably in Ruby

I need a way to determine if one array is a "subarray" of another array when order matters

For instance,

```
a = ["1", "4", "5", "7", "10"]
b = ["1", "4", "5"]
c = ["1", "5", "4"]
d = ["1", "5", "10"]

a includes b = true
a includes c = false
a include d = false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ruakh is this a duplicate if the user wants answer in Ruby?

Comment: @ruakh based on the examples in the test cases given, this is NOT a duplicate I don't think.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568560/difference-between-subarray-subset-subsequence#30287290

Comment: `a include d = false` as non consecutive. I think.

Comment: @iGian thanks, I deleted my comment. I see the OP had this as the `d` array.

Comment: @MarekLipka if this was a dup (to the one linked), then `a include d #=> true`, but OP wants it to return `false`.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because elements must be consecutive.

Comment: I have it reopened.

Comment: @mudasobwa Good one.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks everyone for all the answers.  I guess according to that other post, what I'm actually looking for is a "subarray."

Comment: If anyone has your answer you may consider accepting their answers. You need to click the tic in the top left corner of the answers.

Comment: For your particular example you can do `a.join(' ').match?(b.join(' '))` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[b, c, d].map do |arr|
  a.each_cons(arr.length).any?(&arr.method(:==))
end
#⇒ [true, false, false]
```

This is definitely not the most performant solution, but for not huge arrays is works and, which is important, is readable.

[`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Comment: Could we use `a.each_cons(arr.length).include?(arr)` to achieve same effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["1", "4", "5", "7", "10"]
b = ["1", "4", "5"]
c = ["1", "5", "4"]
d = ["1", "5", "10"]


def sub_set?(arr_a, arr_b)
  arr_a.select.with_index do |a, index|
    arr_b[index] == a
  end == arr_b
end

puts "testing sub_set #{a.inspect} and #{c.inspect}"
puts sub_set?(a,c).inspect
```

Comment: You might use `detect.with_index { |a, i| arr_b[i] != a }` instead of `select` to fail fast.

Comment: Now it does not work at all, it should be `detect {...} ? false : true`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I've spent too much time on getting you guys to first reopen this issue, and now I'm tired. You're answer is better. I'm going to bed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def includes(array)
    return false if array.size > self.size
    indexes = []
    self.each_with_index {|e, i| indexes << i if e == array[0]}
    p indexes
    indexes.each do |i|
      return true if self[i..i+array.size-1] == array
    end
    return false
  end
end

p a.includes b
p a.includes c
p a.includes d
```

Or less phpish :)

```
class Array
  def includes(array)
    return false if array.size > self.size
    indexes = each.with_index.select { |e, i| e == array[0] }.map(&:last)
    indexes.each {|i| self[i..i+array.size-1] == array ? (return true) : (return false)}
  end
end

p a.includes b
p a.includes c
p a.includes d
```

Comment: `indexes = select.with_index { |e, i| e == array[0] }.map(&:last)` would be less phpish.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, it should be `indexes = each.with_index.select { |e, i| e == array[0] }.map(&:last)`, because if `select` goes before `with_index`, it selects plain elements.

Comment: Are you really posting a monkey patch and with 2 versions just with different method names? And 4 space indentations?

Answer (score 0):

You could `join` the elements with an arbitrary character then compare strings:

```
a.join(' ').match?(array.join(' '))
```

This works for the test cases you have provided:

```
a.join(' ').match?(b.join(' '))                                                                                                                     
 #=> true
a.join(' ').match?(c.join(' '))                                                                                                                     
 #=> false
a.join(' ').match?(d.join(' '))                                                                                                                   
 #=> false
```

But this is not a general solution and will fail on varying types of arrays (see comments for further discussion).

Comment: This fails if array contains non-strings. The method should work for any array values.

Comment: Good one. @lacostenycoder `joiner = 1..Float::INFINITY.each { |i| break chr(i) unless a.join.match? chr(i) }`.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Your first sentence is incorrect. If the OP had integer elements instead of string arrays, my approach still works:)

Comment: @SagarPandya I would have done it this way in 30 seconds if I though that was a good answer. What if the array had Hashes or some other non string values? But we have plenty of examples now in any case.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Okay, this is probably not a robust or work-for-all approach, but it can be used in many cases (an array of strings or an array of integers for example). Which may suffice for the OP's needs, so it's worth mentioning as an answer.

Comment: @SagarPandya. I was gonna do it this way but thought I'd get slammed or down voted so I tried to find something which didn't rely on string conversion.  This way is the easy way. I'm suffering from insomnia so sorry for the down vote. But also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174985/how-do-you-check-if-one-array-is-a-subsequence-of-another/50074743#50074743 because this was tagged as duplicate when I started. Make some edit and I'll reverse it.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes I was just looking for a cheeky shortcut, but I should have mentioned its shortcomings in my answer. Your downvote is fine, you have a valid reason. I only dislike downvotes when no or an invalid reason is given.

Comment: This fails for example for `a = ['a b']; b = %w[a b]`.

Comment: Had there been no downvotes I probably wouldn't have upvoted, but I don't think downvotes are deserved, so I've upvoted to offset up to five of them. I don't believe the lack of robustness is a fair objection as the OP's example suggests that all the array elements are strings (of digits).

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's a neat counter example which I should have been aware of. I may delete this answer or at the very least add a caveat alerting the reader to this answers limitations.

Comment: @Cary Ta. Will update my answer to reflect some of the points (including yours) made in the comments. Had I added a commentary in the first place I may have saved others from pointing out the limitations.